# How to hide the jQuery data table before showing in the UI

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to hide the jQuery data table when recordsTotal is 0. But I can see my table hidden only after a second of table display in the UI.

I have used the drawCallback and init event as shown below.

```
$('#table').on('init.dt', function () {
    var totalRecords = table.page.info().recordsTotal;
    if(totalRecords == 0) {
        $('#table_div').hide();
    }
} );

"drawCallback": function() {
    var totalRecords = table.page.info().recordsTotal;
    if(totalRecords == 0) {
        $('#table_div').hide();
    }
}
```

Both of them above snippets, hides the table_div post the display of table, like a splash screen. Any event or callback functions that would solve the purpose? I am using the latest jQuery Data tables version 1.10.9

Comment: Can you hide the table by default, and then only show it if there are records?

Comment: @Tony Hinkle it works.

Comment: Don't forget to use [`columns.adjust()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) when you make table visible. @TonyHinkle, can you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide the table by default and check for records after the page is loaded.  If there are records, then show the table.